# Pass custom product meta data to the order in Woocommerce 4

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to pass custom product meta to the order. I'm able to save the custom product meta in the admin but I'm having an hard time saving the values to the order meta during checkout. I'm using the Woo 4. Can anyone help? I appreciate, thx.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'product_meta_create_email_field' );
function product_meta_create_email_field() {
    $args = array(
        'id'            => 'email_estabelecimento',
        'label'         => __( 'Email do Estabelecimento', 'cfwc' ),
        'class'         => 'cfwc-custom-field',
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'description'   => __( 'Insere aqui o email do estabelecimento.', 'ctwc' ),
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'product_meta_save_email_field' );
function product_meta_save_email_field( $post_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['email_estabelecimento'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'email_estabelecimento', esc_attr( $_POST['email_estabelecimento'] ) );
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_email_as_order_item_meta', 20, 4);
function save_email_as_order_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    if ( $estabelecimento = $values['data']->get_meta('email_estabelecimento') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'email_estabelecimento', $estabelecimento );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, here and there a small adjustment

```php
// Adding a custom field in the back-end
function product_meta_create_email_field() {
    $args = array(
        'id'            => 'email_estabelecimento',
        'label'         => __( 'Email do Estabelecimento', 'cfwc' ),
        'class'         => 'cfwc-custom-field',
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'description'   => __( 'Insere aqui o email do estabelecimento.', 'ctwc' ),
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'product_meta_create_email_field', 10, 0 );

// Saving the custom field value
function product_meta_save_email_field( $post_id ) {
    // Get product
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // $_POST
    $email_estabelecimento = isset( $_POST['email_estabelecimento'] ) ? $_POST['email_estabelecimento'] : '';

    // Update meta data
    $product->update_meta_data( 'email_estabelecimento', esc_attr( $email_estabelecimento ) );

    // Save
    $product->save();

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'product_meta_save_email_field', 10, 1 );

// Displaying custom fields in the WooCommerce order and email confirmations
function save_email_as_order_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    $email_estabelecimento = $values['data']->get_meta('email_estabelecimento');

    if ( isset( $email_estabelecimento ) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'email_estabelecimento', $email_estabelecimento );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_email_as_order_item_meta', 20, 4);
```